# Calling default constructor from another constructor

Tags: java

I am supposed to create a triangle object using 3 points given by the user, and if the triangle isn't legal then create the default one.
Is this a "legal" way to create the default one using the default method, or is this a weird scenario that isn't a way people do things?

```
public class Triangle

private Point _point1;
private Point _point2;
private Point _point3;

public Triangle()
{
    _point1 = new Point(1,0);
    _point2 = new Point(-1,0);
    _point3 = new Point(0,1);
}

public Triangle(Point point1,Point point2,Point point3)
{
    if (isLegal(point1,point2,point3))
        {
        _point1 = new Point(point1);
        _point2 = new Point(point2);
        _point3 = new Point(point3);
        }
    else
        new Triangle();
}
```

Comment: You can call the same-class default constructor using `this();` as the first line of your constructor. That said, a better way to likely go about this would be to have the other constructor call the 3-parameter constructor with the defaults you desired.

Comment: It is "legal", and it's also a weird scenario.  Generally speaking if you try to create an object with bad parameters, it'll throw an IllegalArgumentException rather than giving you an unexpected result.  An example of this would be if you try to create an `ArrayList` with a negative initial capacity.  But this sounds like an assignment to teach you about constructors, so it's expected it may be a bit contrived.

Comment: @azurefrog Yea this assignment is there to teach about constructors, and originally the code under the 'else' was just a copy of the default constructor I created. Since this is a re-use of the same code figure I might as well just call the other constructor.

Comment: You code does not look very much like Java code ( `{`  in new lines), `_` as variable prefix). Did you learn it like this?

Comment: @Datz The { in new lines is a habbit back from when i learned C in high-school, and i just like it since its easier to notice if i missed one or not.
Regarding the _ as variable is prefix, yea thats how they want me to do it, but only under object methods, in the main() im supposed to use em as normal words (also finals are always in caps).

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to have multiple constructors, and one constructor can call another. This is called constructor chaining.

Use this() within a constructor to refer to another constructor for the same class. Use super() to refer to a constructor of the superclass. The arguments you pass to this or super decide which constructor gets called.

Create a primary constructor that takes all the arguments you need. Then you can have secondary constructors that call another constructor, passing in default values.

The call to this() or super() has to be the first statement in the constructor. This is a problem for what you want to do. Handling validation separately from construction is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem like this (code cleaned up a little):

```
public class Triangle {
    private final Point point1;
    private final Point point2;
    private final Point point3;

    public Triangle() {
        this(new Point(1, 0), new Point(-1, 0), new Point(0, 1));
    }

    public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) {
        if (!isLegal(point1, point2, point3)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Points are illegal");
        }
        this.point1 = point1;
        this.point2 = point2;
        this.point3 = point3;
        // or if you need a copy constructor
        // this.point1 = new Point(point1);
        // this.point2 = new Point(point2);
        // this.point3 = new Point(point3);
    }

    public static boolean isLegal(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) {
        // some magic calculations
        return result;
    }
}
```

and finally create your `Triangle` like this with your existing points `p1`, `p2`, `3`:

```
final Triangle t = Triangle.isLegal(p1, p2, p3) ? new Triangle(p1, p2, p3) : new Triangle();
```

or

```
Triangle t;
if(Triangle.isLegal(p1, p2, p3)) {
    t = new Triangle(p1, p2, p3);
} else {
    t = new Triangle();
}
```

The static method `isLegal` is used to check your parameters before the constructor is called.
The check inside the constructor ensures that the constructor with the three points is not used with illegal arguments. If the given points are "illegal" the exception is thrown and quits your application if it is not caught somewhere (*Google: java exception*).

Comment: I do not understand the throw new IllegalArgumentException("Points are illegal"); , it is not something we've learned so far, and doubt I can use.
Also, im failing to understand where exactly that
final Triangle t = Triangle.isLegal(p1, p2, p3) ? new Triangle(p1, p2, p3) : new Triangle();
goes(?)

Comment: @Croompy I added some explanations and improved the no-argument constructor to use `this(...)` what you wanted to use